# How do I group functions in ES6 Modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

How do you group functions in a ES6 Module package? In CommonJS packages you can do this.

```
// package.js
const startSession = require("./startSession");

module.exports = {
  hooks: {
    startSession,
  },
};


// client.js
const { hooks: {startSession } } = require("package");
// OR
const { startSession } = require("package").hooks;
```

It looks like the similar syntax in ES6 code isn't supported.

```
import { hooks: {startSession } } from "packageX";
```

On source for that, is this babel issue from 2016. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4996

Another is the official documentation, that doesn't really mentioning this kind of syntax.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

**Solutions**

One solutions in ES6 javascript is this.

```
// package.js
import startSession from "./hooks/start-session";
export const hooks = {
  startSession
};

// client.js
import { hooks } from "package";
const { startSession } = hooks;
```

But I would like to write the import in one line. Maybe not possible?

This is not what I look for.

```
import { hooks } from "package"; const { startSession } = hooks;
```

This kind of syntax would be nice, but how do you set up the packages, if possible?

```
import { startSession } from "packageX/hooks";
import { startSession } from "packageX".hooks;
```

Any other suggestions?

**Answer**

Estus below pushed me in the right direction. Here is a more detailed answer.

```
// package.json
"main": "src/index.js",
"exports": {
    ".": "./src/index.js",
    "./hooks": "./src/hooks/index.js",
}

// src/hooks/start-session.js
export default () => {}

// src/hooks/index.js
export * as startSession from "./start-session";

// src/index.js
export const doSomething () => {}

// client.js
import { doSomething } from "packageX";
import { startSession } from "packageX/hooks";
```

Comment: If you want to import it like `from 'packageX/hooks'`, create a subdirectory named `hooks` and create a file named `index.js` inside which contains `export startSession`.

Comment: You can even have hooks dir with nested package.json inside that refers to main file outside hooks so nested entry point doesn't define how modules are structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES modules are supposed to be statically analyzed so nested imports that result from expressions are impossible. Import syntax isn't destructuring, just looks similarly. It is [strictly specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#syntax); if a feature isn't there, it's not supported.

This should be preferably avoided as this prevents `hooks` properties from being tree-shaken (not applicable to Node currently).

For an entry point or barrel module, prefixes can be used to give an export a scope:

```
export { default as hookStartSession } from "./hooks/start-session";
```

And this is a way this is usually done when an import has some scope, at least if a package exposes additional public entry point.

```
import { startSession } from "packageX/hooks"
```

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for. I usually put my code in /src and have "main": "src" in my package.json. But with this solutions it looks like I need to put the hooks folder in my project root. Can this be configured from package.json?

Comment: This depends whether you aim at transpiled or native modules. For CJS you need to have dummy hooks/package.json that has 'main' that refers to entry point. For native ESM there's no need for this, root package.json should have 'modules', https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was looking for. I have touched all the settings before, but didn't really get it right. You totally pushed me in the right direction. Now my code will look much better.